# live agent using lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, liveagent

One of my clients is keen on using Lightning experience looking at the nice and interactive UI layer, but we also need to keep the live agent functionality since this is a client service and live agent is a key channel for addressing many customer issues.

Can we make live agent compatible with lightning Experience, if this is not enabled how much of an effort is it to recreate in a lightning component?

Comment: I saw this on the appexchange and it was mentioned in the developer forum, maybe you can check it out: https://start-indexless-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/packagingSetupUI/ipLanding.app?apvId=04t61000000Tmnp

Comment: here is the developer forum thread https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000MJ5mIAG

Comment: @Anil First of all live agent is only for Service console. You can see idea has been raised to bring it to sales cloud https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000krmGAAQ . And I am not sure which lightning experience you are talking about lightning experience is coming for service console but it is in Beta. I don't think you are going to use the beta product for client. So my guess is that you need to go with Service Console (which will have lightning styles but not exactly lightning) and use live agent. Could you please provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

Live Agent is on the [roadmap](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_roadmap.htm&language=en_US&type=0) for Lightning Experience, but listed as "Future (Through Spring '18)", so you'll need to wait a few releases to use it.

You can still make use of Live Agent APIs(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_understanding_resources.htm) to recreate it, but I believe it would need quite some work.

Best option might be to stay on the Service Console in Classic, and switch to Service Cloud in Lightning Experience once it's out of Beta and have all the features you need.